# Hex to Binary, results reversed?

Tags: python

I'm learning about dictionaries and my text book gives an example of a function that converts hex to binary. When I typed out the code myself, the result was reversed.

I checked my code carefully and it matches textbook.

Can someone give some insight into what's going here?

The textbook code & return value:
[image]

my code:

```
hexToBinaryTable = {'0':'0000', '1':'0001', '2':'0010', '3':'0011', '4':'0100', '5':'0101', \
                    '6':'0110', '7':'0111', '8':'1000', '9':'1001', 'A':'1010', 'B':'1011', \
                    'C':'1100', 'D':'1101', 'E':'1110', 'F':'1111'}

def convert(number, table):
    binary = ""
    for digit in number:
        binary = table[digit] + binary
    return binary

convert("35A", hexToBinaryTable)
```

returns:

'101001010011'

Comment: Yes, well spotted. It does indeed look like your textbook reverses the order of the groups of binary digits it returns.

Comment: It should be `binary = binary + table[digit]`.

Comment: They have a bug in their code. It should be `binary = binary + table[digit]`, or `binary += table[digit]`.

Comment: Oh! I would never have guessed that the order mattered. Thanks!

Comment: @AfterVirtue It definately matters. Compare `print("a" + "b")` and `print("b" + "a")`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate great point, I should have thought of the fact that the binary variable is a string and so commutative property doesn't apply.

Comment: @AfterVirtue Yes, exactly. `+` is only commutative for numeric classes (and potentially user-defined classes that also follow that property). The fact that `+` can be defined for any class complicates matters a bit when reasoning about what it does.